# Is there an intuitive reason for why the homomorphisms among fields are injective or trivial?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given $F$ and $S$ are two nontrivial fields, we know that if $\varphi \colon S \to F$ is a ring homomorphism, $\varphi$ is either trivial or injective.

This is a simple consequence by the trivial structure of the ideals in a field.

But is there any other explanations for this that are more intuitive?

(I know this question is poorly stated, but I just feel like there has to be a different perspective on this result.)

Comment: It is not unreasonable to think that the non-injectivity of a ring homomorphim is related to the existence of non-invertible elements.

Comment: I wouldn’t say that the question is poorly stated. However, I have the feeling  that things are becoming intuitive with practice rather than with some magic. Becoming familiar with ideals (I.e. with exercises) as you mention maybe a way to get intuitions.

Comment: Interestingly, I think the argument about ideals is super intuitive: Ideals are exactly the possible kernels of homomorphisms. So naturally, if there are only trivial ideals, then there are only trivial kernels, and then there are only trivial homomorphisms. It really depends on how you view the objects you're using in the argument. (By trivial I mean simple, not the 0 homomorphism)